# Paint Bucket in C

Tags: c++, c, paint, borland-c++

i need help.. I'm making a function that imitates the bucket in paint.. the problem comes when half the image is colored this error occurs "NTVM has encounter an illegal instruction"

here is my "bucket" code:

```
void bucket(int x, int y, int fillColor)
{

 if(getpixel(x,y)==getpixel(x,y+1)){
     putpixel(x,y,fillColor);
     bucket(x,y+1,fillColor);
 }


 if(getpixel(x,y)==getpixel(x+1,y)){
     putpixel(x,y,fillColor);
     bucket(x+1,y,fillColor);
 }


 if(getpixel(x,y)==getpixel(x,y-1)){
     putpixel(x,y,fillColor);
     bucket(x,y-1,fillColor);
 }


 if(getpixel(x,y)==getpixel(x-1,y)){
     putpixel(x,y,fillColor);
     bucket(x-1,y,fillColor);
 }


}
```

supposedly the problems with "fills" algorithms is that your stack of recursion doesn't support all the calls ... at least half the drawing is colored..

PS: I'm running it on Borland c++ v3.1 using the

Comment: Tangential, but that's probably going to be slow as a dog for large inputs.  for something like this I would prefer an iterative solution and would not call a function like `getpixel` multiple times for every pixel.  Image processing is one area where sound design principles (i.e., throw common logic into a function) may break down because what are typically trivial and unimportant inefficiencies become noticeable.

Comment: yeah it is actually sloooow, when i run the code it can be seen how it is filling the area, originally i was doing it iterative but after researching the `floodfill` function i thought it was better recursively.... *testing iterative... thnx for answering

Comment: No problem.  But yeah, unless your language supports it you're not going to be able to get away with a recursive approach when you know that the level of recursion is going to be very deep (and this cannot be tail call optimized either).  And as far as the functions go; lose 'em.  It takes a lot longer to setup a function, call it, and return then it does to index into an `unsigned char[]` (or something similar) which holds your image data.  We're talking millions of wasted cycles.

Comment: The problem you're trying to solve is called a "flood fill".  There's a pretty good analysis of the different techniques you can use here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6017/QuickFill-An-efficient-flood-fill-algorithm

Comment: I think you something at the end of your question ;)

Answer (score 1):

I would guess dollars to donuts, you are blowing up your stack.  NTVM is a dos emulator for windows.  I would guess it has a limited stack.  Attempting to address memory outside of the stack(Addressable range) would cause an illegal instruction.  This would also explain why you only get it for large pictures.

Comment: :S yeah now i get it why only the half of the drawing.. sooo.. guess I'll have to make it iterative thnx for the explanation of NTVM

Answer (score 1):

In the code you're running the recursion never ends... you should stop the recursion when the bucket gets to the border of image (top, bottom, left or right).

There is also another problem: each call of function calls four other functions. That means the recursion will never end even if you add special if for image borders, because for example bucket on pixel (x,y) calls bucket(x+1,y) and bucket on pixel (x+1,y) calls bucket(x-1,y) which is in fact pixel (x,y) again!

My advice for you is to add special function arguments like ,,direction''. Consider four directions: N,E,W and S. First call of bucket calls 4 buckets, but this time with direction. The function with direction==N doesn't color in S direction. You can use integer values from 0 (no direction on first call) up to 4 for direction symbols.

Of course my idea needs further development to optimize the code (the conditions should be better stated so we will not access the same pixels multiple times).

Comment: This is just wrong, assuming fillcolor is different from the color of the first pixel.  The recursion will end eventually because when its called on an old pixel, it's color will have changed already.  While recursion for this purpose Is a horrible idea for many reasons, none of them actually answer the question.  Your counter suggestion won't work either because from how I read it, it will color 4 lines in four directions without coloring anything else.

Comment: Yes, recursion is not a good idea, but I assumed OP wanted to check recursion in this problem for academic purposes;) My counter suggestion was just a small hint. I haven't specified how to use directions: next calls may not keep the direction but also call bucket sideways.